# Weather Indicator Unity/12.10

Tags: 12.10, unity, indicator, weather

As the title suggests, I am looking for a weather indicator for Unity on 12.10. I tried indicator-weather and I can't click apply after adding a city (apparently I am not the only one with this problem, based on googling). I tried my-weather-indicator, but the PPA can not be found after adding it, so that doesn't seem to work either. I know I can get some weather information via the cities scope, but that is not really what I want. Is there anything else out there (or does anyone have a fix for my problems)?

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: I got indicator-weather kind of working by manually adding the location information using the dconf-editor. Unfortunately it still can not get extended forecast info.

Comment: I think this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/weather-indicator/+bug/1162485) might be your problem?  If you look at the one of comments it looks like one of the keys for getting the weather has expired and a new one hasn't been generated.  Hope this helps.

Comment: jjesse, I think that this is the problem. It doesn't look like it is going to be fixed, however. I'm open to alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install my-weather-indicator using this .deb

http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu/pool/main/m/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator_0.6.3-0extras12.10.3_all.deb

Seems to work fine.

Comment: You shouldn't directly use a deb. Instead, you should add that PPA to your software sources and install using apt.